# Смена группы пользователя при достижении определенной суммы покупок

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.

Мне нужно построить следующую логику: При определенной сумме покупок группа пользователя должна меняться.

Я пытаюсь сделать следующим образом.

```
$customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id ); // Получю йд пользоветяля
$total_spent = $customer->get_total_spent(); // Получаю сумму покупок

if ($total_spent > 1000) {
   //меняю группу...
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в `$total_spent` всегда лежит 0, хотя в админке показывает другую сумму совершенных покупок. Подскажите как можно реализовать данную логику другими путями или улучить мой.

Заранее спасибо!

Как работает `$customer->get_total_spent()`

```
/**
 * Get total spent by customer.
 *
 * @param  int $user_id User ID.
 * @return string
 */
function wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id ) {
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
    return $customer->get_total_spent();
}
```

Comment: $customer->get_total_spent() как работает?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Дополнил в вопросе

Comment: странный пример для `$customer->get_total_spent()` - Вы не ошиблись?

Comment: @phpBear Нет, не ошибся. 
Вот есть плагин b2b плагин для WC и там есть функционал выдавать группы. Какими методами можно менять эти группы средствами php или запросами в бд. А менять их при условиях когда get_total_spent() больше определённого значения.

Comment: Почему я спросил. Вы создаете класс. У него вызываете метод, а в пример приводите метод который опять же создает этот же класс и снова вызывает этот же метод. Либо Вы в примере ошиблись, либо в описании.

Answer (score 0):

Для покупателей в WooCommerce, есть функция **wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id )**. Есть два отличных примера в ответах на разных площадках, как менять статус юзера [на иностранном стаке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770912/woocommerce-change-user-role-on-purchase) и [стакэксчендж](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120656/woocommerce-change-user-role-after-completing-order), повешать проверочку на

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_role_on_purchase' );
```

или

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed','change_role_on_purchase' );
```

Просто надо повешать проверочку (wc_get_customer_total_spent) для текущего пользователя, если он авторизован или из проверяемого ордера.